# Who's my friend?

Tags: riddle

I've got a friend who's a real great guy!

- He loves a drink.
- He'll help you change your car tyres.
- This one time, he met an alien and got a coat out of it.
- This other time, he got talking to a space sorcerer-monk and they were discussing acting award results - they seemed really keen on Laurence Olivier 1983, BAFTA 1976, Emmy 1989, Emmy 2001 & Laurence Olivier 2009.

He can be a bit risky to be aroundthough ...

- Any time you greet him, he tends to try and take over.
- He can a be racist sometimes - he once said if he were from Africa, he was sure he'd be gambling all the time.

Who's my friend?

Comment: If this gets solved really quickly, I'd love to know whether I made it too easy (was one of the clues too obvious?) and any suggestions for how to improve it.

Comment: He once stalked Sean Bean to kill a giant...

Answer (score 6):

I think it's

> Jack

Because

> The drink is Jack Daniels.
>  The tool to lift a car is called jack.
>  The man is probably Jack Harkness from Doctor Who.
>  The fourth line is probably a reference to some films. I haven't found the movies yet, but I know that in 2001 there was a "Jack the ripper" movie.

Comment: You've got the answer right, and the first two of your explanations, the 2nd two aren't right though.

Comment: 1976 has "Jackson County Jail", 1989 has "Jacknife",2009 has "Jackboots on Whitehall", but 1983 has nothing containing "Jack", except for an Oscar for Jack Nicholson.

Comment: @dmg the last of these is closer than the others. If this doesn't get solved today I add a little more specificity to that one to help.

Comment: Ah, it occurs to me that if you search for the name without the "k", you may do better

Comment: The 3rd and 4th is very similar in structure to the two that @Chamberlain got. I've tweaked the hint to the 4th to be a bit more specific

Comment: @dmg in 1983 keen on Laurence Olivier, might refer to the TV film: Mr. Halpern and Mr. Johnson Where he worked together with Jackie Gleason which is about 2 friends where one is in love with the other

Comment: @ChenOrihara Also, in some of these years, there are actors with the name Jack who've won BAFTAs and Emmys.

Answer (score 6):

[Chamberlain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17283/4513) got the good qualities, and I think I have the bad ones:

Any time you greet him, he tends to try and take over.

> "Hi, Jack!" = hijack, meaning seize or take over.

He can a be racist sometimes - he once said if he were from Africa, he was sure he'd be gambling all the time.

> He would be "Black Jack" = blackjack, a casino card game.
>  (And it is indeed a bit racist to imply all Africans are black lol)

Comment: Well done those two are exactly right :)

The 3rd and 4th is very similar in structure to these two, and I've tweaked the hint to the 4th to be a bit more specific.

Comment: could the third be Space jacket? since an you meet an alien in space and a space jacket is a coat thats widely available

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe nobody has got the 3rd clue yet...

> *This one time, he met an alien and got a coat out of it.* - ET is an alien and Jack+ET = jacket = coat.

Comment: Correct :) Nearly all done!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the above answers

> Derek 'Jac'obi fits the 4th clue.

Comment: Correct ... have you understood why, or is he just the only thing that all those award years have in common?

Who's the space sorcerer-monk?

Comment: @Brondahl **Obi**-Wan Kenobi, right?

Comment: @randal'thor, yep ... indeed, Jack + obi-wan =  Jacobi won :)

Comment: @Brondahl Shall I add that to my answer, or edit it into this answer?